# How to force devtools to install packages in remotes

Tags: r, devtools

`devtools` package introduces a nice concept of adding dependancies not available in CRAN, into DESCRIPTION file (described in the  [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html)). However, I have not been able to figure out how to get it to install the dependancies automatically. The vignette linked above certainly hints that is possible and the install command certainly parses for the "remote" (got an error when they were not specified correctly), however, it only installed dependancies from CRAN. Anybody has ideas if there are some parameters I should specify to make the installation automatic?

Thusfar, I have tried `install`, `install_bitbucket` and `install_local`. `install` managed to download all the dependancies available in CRAN. `install_bitbucket` did the same and `install_local` just did not work at all.

Comment: What exactly did you run to attempt to install these packages? Where you using `devtools::install_github()`? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Remotes:` field is used to tell devtools where to look for the packages that are listed in the standard `Depends:`, `Imports:` and `Suggests:`.

So make sure that you have the package listed in the appropriate standard field, and its source listed in Remotes. Then running the following should install these packages from the Remotes source:

```
devtools::install_deps()
```